# how to remove duplicate records with different columns in Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle

i have a problem with removing duplicate data in rows with different Columns :

```
SELECT   p1, p2

  FROM   (SELECT   'A' AS p1, 'B' AS p2 FROM DUAL
          UNION
          SELECT   'B' AS p1, 'A' AS p2 FROM DUAL) a;
```

and the result will be :

```
P1 P2 
-- -- 
A , B  
B , A
```

**and I just need A,B or B,A**

Comment: Which one do you need A,B, or B,A. Is it ok to sort alphabetically? Like always A,B instead of B,A, and A,C instead of C,A?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle SQL : find unique combination and order alphabetically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474179/oracle-sql-find-unique-combination-and-order-alphabetically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT   distinct least(p1, p2), greatest(p1, p2)
  FROM   (SELECT   'A' AS p1, 'B' AS p2 FROM DUAL
          UNION
          SELECT   'B' AS p1, 'A' AS p2 FROM DUAL) a;
```