# Oracle SQL : find unique combination and order alphabetically

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data like below: (columns Name1 and Name2) as a result of another query.

Name1 Name2

A     B

B     A

However, any such pairings should actually be considered just one, and should be only reported as A B (A comes before B , alphabetically sorted)

How do I do it in Oracle / PlSQL?

Comment: What kind of "data"? Is this two rows with two columns each? Or two result sets with two rows of one column each?

Comment: @Thilo edited the question. 2 rows, having 2 columns each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name1, Name2
FROM (
      SELECT Name1, Name2 FROM t WHERE Name1 <= Name2
      UNION ALL
      SELECT Name2, Name1 FROM t WHERE Name1 > Name2
     );
```

Which should work and is quite simple, but is not as efficient as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       CASE WHEN Name1 <= Name2 THEN Name1 ELSE Name2 END AS Name1
      ,CASE WHEN Name1 <= Name2 THEN Name2 ELSE Name1 END AS Name2
FROM t;
```

or just:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       LEAST(Name1, Name2) AS Name1
      ,GREATEST(Name1, Name2) AS Name2
FROM t;
```

I have not considered NULLs in these queries. You'd have to modify the <= comparisons to take these into account, if the columns are nullable.

Comment: perfect, i know the 2nd answer is more efficient, but the 1st answer is really a clever solution which I like.

Comment: Added a 3rd option which I prefer most of all - simple, and efficient.